# Any issues with trying to go 2x10 with 44/22 rings?

Tags: crankset, derailleur

I figure I would need a triple derailleur for the cage height, but IDK if the ramps and pins would be sufficient for that kind of gap. The 44t chainrings are designed for 3x10.

Also, there might be a range gap as well, but I'm not worried given I ride fixed-gear in the city.

I’m obsessed with max range. This would make parts easier to find, vs 3x10.

Comment: You would need to remake the nut counterbore on the 44 on the other side, which is a project and requires a sufficiently thick chainring. I've done it and posted about it here if you search "counterbore."

Comment: Also, 104/64 rings are very well supplied and interchangeable. It doesn't get much easier to find.

Answer (score 3):

Changing down is probably okay - the front mech simply pushes the chain off and it hopefully falls down onto the little ring.

Changing back up to the big ring will be difficult because of the 22 tooth difference.  You may have to stop riding, and move it by hand, or you might get away with pedalling very gently while leaning on the lever, until it catches the chain and drags it around the bigger chainring.

Also consider the rear derailleur's capacity rating - I'd guess you want a wide-range cassette like 11 to 40+, which probably limits you to mountain bike groupsets.   GRX might be worth looking at.

You don't need a triple derailleur with only two chainrings, you may need to "rotate" the cage a little so the chain has clearance both at the top and at the bottom.  Worst cast, you may need to fabricate new cage side plates.

You might also benefit from using a friction-front shifter.  This will give you more precise feel and control over exactly where the chain is.    An indexed shifter will struggle with the upshift.

Comment: There might be a clearance: small chainring - chain stay. OP does not tell us whether the frame is a 2x or a 3x.